# Windows Update error 0x80072EE2

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-sbs-2003, wsus, automatic-updates

I use Windows Server Update Services to manage updates for my SBS 2003 R2 domain. My clients are receiving error code 0x80072EE2 when they try to scan for updates. In typical microsoft style, there's no documentation for the error code. Anyone have any clue what it means? Here's the relevant portion of the WindowsUpdate.log file from one of the failing clients:

---

```
2009-05-12  16:11:29:416    1020    1450    Setup   SelfUpdate check completed.  SelfUpdate is NOT required.
2009-05-12  16:12:29:531    1020    1450    PT  +++++++++++  PT: Synchronizing server updates  +++++++++++
2009-05-12  16:12:29:541    1020    1450    PT    + ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}, Server URL = http://SBS:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2009-05-12  16:12:31:827    1020    1450    PT  WARNING: Cached cookie has expired or new PID is available
2009-05-12  16:12:31:827    1020    1450    PT  Initializing simple targeting cookie, clientId = 0efe255a-cb28-409f-9004-38dcd9790994, target group = , DNS name = copernicus.tigranetworks.local
2009-05-12  16:12:31:827    1020    1450    PT    Server URL = http://SBS:8530/SimpleAuthWebService/SimpleAuth.asmx
2009-05-12  16:13:35:288    1020    1450    Misc    WARNING: SendRequest failed with hr = 80072ee2. Proxy List used:  Bypass List used : > Auth Schemes used : 
2009-05-12  16:13:35:288    1020    1450    PT    + Last proxy send request failed with hr = 0x80072EE2, HTTP status code = 0
2009-05-12  16:13:35:288    1020    1450    PT    + Caller provided proxy = No
2009-05-12  16:13:35:288    1020    1450    PT    + Proxy list used = sbs:8080
2009-05-12  16:13:35:288    1020    1450    PT    + Bypass list used = 
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    PT    + Caller provided credentials = No
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    PT    + Impersonate flags = 0
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    PT    + Possible authorization schemes used = 
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    PT  WARNING: GetCookie failure, error = 0x80072EE2, soap client error = 5, soap error code = 0, HTTP status code = 200
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    PT  WARNING: PTError: 0x80072ee2
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    PT  WARNING: GetCookie_WithRecovery failed : 0x80072ee2
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    PT  WARNING: RefreshCookie failed: 0x80072ee2
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    PT  WARNING: RefreshPTState failed: 0x80072ee2
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    PT  WARNING: Sync of Updates: 0x80072ee2
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    PT  WARNING: SyncServerUpdatesInternal failed: 0x80072ee2
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    Agent     * WARNING: Failed to synchronize, error = 0x80072EE2
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    Agent     * WARNING: Exit code = 0x80072EE2
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    Agent   *********
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    Agent   *************
2009-05-12  16:13:35:289    1020    1450    Agent   WARNING: WU client failed Searching for update with error 0x80072ee2
2009-05-12  16:13:35:293    1020    1bd0    AU  >>##  RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {529605DD-E2A8-469D-9DEB-38E777C6047C}]
2009-05-12  16:13:35:293    1020    1bd0    AU    # WARNING: Search callback failed, result = 0x80072EE2
2009-05-12  16:13:35:293    1020    1bd0    AU    # WARNING: Failed to find updates with error code 80072EE2
2009-05-12  16:13:35:293    1020    1bd0    AU  #########
2009-05-12  16:13:35:293    1020    1bd0    AU  ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates [CallId = {529605DD-E2A8-469D-9DEB-38E777C6047C}]
2009-05-12  16:13:35:293    1020    1bd0    AU  #############
2009-05-12  16:13:35:293    1020    1bd0    AU  Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2009-05-12  16:13:35:293    1020    1bd0    AU  AU setting next detection timeout to 2009-05-12 19:13:22
2009-05-12  16:13:35:293    1020    1bd0    AU  Setting AU scheduled install time to 2009-05-13 07:00:00
2009-05-12  16:13:35:293    1020    1bd0    AU  Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2009-05-12  16:13:35:294    1020    1bd0    AU  Successfully wrote event for AU health state:0
2009-05-12  16:13:40:290    1020    1450    Report  REPORT EVENT: {8FD4EA60-BA78-42B3-9B92-1C7CDD217271}    2009-05-12 16:13:35:289+0100    1   148 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   80072ee2    AutomaticUpdates    Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80072ee2.
2009-05-12  16:13:40:348    1020    1450    Report  CWERReporter::HandleEvents - WER report upload completed with status 0x8
2009-05-12  16:13:40:348    1020    1450    Report  WER Report sent: 7.3.7100.0 0x80072ee2 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Scan 101 Managed
2009-05-12  16:13:40:348    1020    1450    Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2009-05-12  16:18:26:964    1020    1450    PT  WARNING: Cached cookie has expired or new PID is available
2009-05-12  16:18:26:964    1020    1450    PT  Initializing simple targeting cookie, clientId = 0efe255a-cb28-409f-9004-38dcd9790994, target group = , DNS name = copernicus.tigranetworks.local
2009-05-12  16:18:26:964    1020    1450    PT    Server URL = http://SBS:8530/SimpleAuthWebService/SimpleAuth.asmx
2009-05-12  16:18:27:111    1020    1450    Report  Uploading 2 events using cached cookie, reporting URL = http://SBS:8530/ReportingWebService/ReportingWebService.asmx
2009-05-12  16:18:29:980    1020    1450    Report  Reporter successfully uploaded 2 events.
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a missing SelftUpdate virtual directory in IIS. Recreating the virtual directory and pointing it to the appropriate files solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

There is a Microsoft Support article (KB 836941) mentioned in this blog post which addresses this error number:

[You may encounter temporary connection-related errors when you use Windows Update or Microsoft Update to install updates](https://blog.mikewconsulting.com/tag/httpsupport-microsoft-comkb836941/)

> In most cases, these messages are
>   temporary or short-lived issues that
>   are caused by very slight
>   interruptions in communications
>   between the computer that is being
>   updated and the Windows update
>   servers. These issues are generally
>   self-healing. So, before you try the
>   troubleshooting methods in this
>   article, please exit the Windows
>   Update site, wait 10 to 15 minutes,
>   start Windows Update again, and then
>   check for updates. You can also let
>   Windows Automatic Update install the
>   updates on its usual 24-hour cycle.
>
> Note: These errors can occur even if no changes have been made to network settings.

Proposed resolutions:

> **Method A: Verify Internet connectivity**
>
> Make sure that you can successfully
>   access other Web sites. If you can’t
>   successfully access other Web sites,
>   your Internet connection may not be
>   working correctly, and you might want
>   to contact your Internet service
>   provider for help.
>
> If you can successfully access other
>   Web sites, continue with Method B.
>
> **Method B:** Make sure that Windows Firewall is turned on, and temporarily
>   disable third-party firewalls
>
> Warning This workaround may make a
>   computer or a network more vulnerable
>   to attack by malicious users or by
>   malicious software such as viruses. We
>   do not recommend this workaround but
>   are providing this information so that
>   you can implement this workaround at
>   your own discretion. Use this
>   workaround at your own risk.
>
> **Method C:** Temporarily disable third-party antivirus software
>
> **Method D:** Disable software accelerator programs
>
> **Method E:** Add the Windows Update Web site and the Microsoft Update Web site to the Trusted Sites list
>
> **Method F:** Make sure that you have the latest Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) update installed

Comment: Actually, there is a very useful list of error numbers in that article. Thanks.

Comment: @TimLong. not anymore... The link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

I have a windows update error 0x80072EE2 (which means = ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT). I just simply assign the dns server at my IPv4 properties that ISP server provides and it works. - Allan(toshiba tech support)

Answer (score 0):

Splattne's answer should be marked as the correct one, but I would add:

- Make sure the BITS service is started, not just updated

This has caught me a few times.

Comment: I've voted him up but I don't want to be a hasty ent and mark it as The One Answer too quickly.